# Problem with sorting crypto currency prices (vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sorting

I have a problem with the sort() method, and i cant figure it out.

So basically I have a table with crypto currencies from an api, and it can sort per column.
everything works fine (Rank, Name, MarketCap, etc) except the price of the coin. This just doesn't sort correctly. for example the price of BTC always ends up somewhere in the middle. The price from the api is a String.

[Photo of table with cryptos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ctq4H.png)

This is the method I use for sorting.

```
 sortBy (prop) {
  if (this.sorter === 'inc') {
    this.cryptos.sort((a, b) => a[prop] > b[prop] ? 1 : -1)
    this.sorter = 'dec'
  } else {
    this.cryptos.sort((a, b) => a[prop] > b[prop] ? -1 : 1)
    this.sorter = 'inc'
  }
},
```

And this is the way I call the method

```
 <tr>
    <th class="table-header table-link" v-on:click="sortBy('rank')">Rank</th>
    <th class="table-header">Icon</th>
    <th class="table-header table-link" v-on:click="sortBy('name')">Name</th>
    <th class="table-header">Symbol</th>
    <th class="table-header table-link" v-on:click="sortBy('price')">Price</th>
    <th class="table-header table-link" v-on:click="sortBy('change')">{{time}}</th>
    <th class="table-header table-link" v-on:click="sortBy('marketCap')">Market Cap</th>
 </tr>
```

Example of amounts that are coming through (keep in mind that they are coming through as a String):

```
464.2807003746
15150.0527417405
0.5010685149
0.8374992554
0.5010685149 
66.5544823869
233.8180345945
4.2255392708
10.9344985436
0.1363374574
0.16150966
```

I hope I gave enough info, and maybe someone can help me with this.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: since they are string, are they sorted like this : 1, 15, 166, 2, 20, 3, 34 ? I believe you should use `parseFloat(prop)` in your sortBy function, but only for float or int values (not for name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.sort()` sorts strings in lexicographical order (the JS engine checks the number character by character), so you need to convert these to numbers.

```
// It's great for sorting strings
[
  `464.2807003746`, 
  `15150.0527417405`, 
  `0.5010685149`
].sort((a, b) => a > b ? 1 : -1)
//=> [('0.5010685149', '15150.0527417405', '464.2807003746')];

// Convert strings to numbers
[
  `464.2807003746`, 
  `15150.0527417405`, 
  `0.5010685149`
].sort((a, b) => Number(a) > Number(b) ? 1 : -1)
//=> "0.5010685149", "464.2807003746", "15150.0527417405"]


// Convert strings to numbers implicitly
[
  `464.2807003746`, 
  `15150.0527417405`, 
  `0.5010685149`
].sort((a, b) => a - b)
//=> "0.5010685149", "464.2807003746", "15150.0527417405"]
```

You can include a conditional in your `sortBy` method and check if the `prop` is the price.

Comment: `..].map(Number).sort(..` might be more efficient than applying on each check

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, ah yes, or we can convert them implicitly: `.sort((a, b) => a - b)`

Comment: Thanks alot! It works now! I actually already tried to change it to numbers. But I probably did something wrong.

Comment: @MauritsBrouwer Glad to hear it works now. If you think it solved your problem, you can also accept my answer ;)